# What is the most efficient way to combine this array of arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get two arrays of arrays (I think that means they're multidimensional) combined/merged together by a shared value. In other words, similar to the JOIN statement in SQL. Is there a specific, efficient way to go about this?

Trying to merge these two:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => alice
            [2] => car
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => bob
            [2] => truck
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => charlie
            [2] => bike
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => alice
            [2] => Vancouver
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => bob
            [2] => Toronto
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => charlie
            [2] => Portland
        )

)
```

To produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => alice
            [2] => car
            [3] => Vancouver
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => bob
            [2] => truck
            [3] => Toronto
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => charlie
            [2] => bike
            [3] => Portland
        )

)
```

Comment: you want "join by id" ? may be best to have that id to be array index.

Comment: also, i prefer to second level arrray to be assoc, to not mix the things

Comment: agreed with @eicto - it would be a *lot* easier to get a good solution to this if you had an array with named keys rather than [1],[2],[3]. In fact, I'd go so far as to say that this is required in order for your system to be robust. Because who's to say there can't be a city named 'Bike', or a person named 'Truck'? And if you have any possibility of ambiguity in the data, then you can't use any answers that include 'array_unique' or `array_merge`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    $result[$key] = array_unique(array_merge($a[$key], $b[$key]));
}
```

I'd go with something like this. First merge the both arrays and then sort out duplicate items. This of course requires that both arrays have the same length and numeric indicies.

Answer (score 0):

"Optimally" you wouldn't have two arrays in the first place.

A solution for this *specific* case:

```
$a1 = [
  [5, 'alice', 'car'],
  [3, 'bob', 'truck'],
  [5, 'charlie', 'bike'],
];

$a2 = [
  [5, 'alice', 'Vancouver'],
  [3, 'bob', 'Toronto'],
  [5, 'charlie', 'Portland']
];

$a3 = array_map(function($a, $b) { $a[] = $b[2]; return $a; }, $a1, $a2);
```

Results in (partial):

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(4) {
    [0] =>
    int(5)
    [1] =>
    string(5) "alice"
    [2] =>
    string(3) "car"
    [3] =>
    string(9) "Vancouver"
  }
...
```

If you don't need to keep `$a1` around, you're really not going to get a better solution than:

```
foreach ($a1 as $key => $val)
  $a1[$key][] = $a2[$key][2];
```